# Align the columns of tables in HAML/HTML

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml, bootstrap-4

I am making a table that is filled out dynamically. When filling out the contents dynamically, I can get null objects. When I get the null objects the HTML table is not aligned properly. For example I want to create a table as follow:

```
    Header1       Header2        Header3       Header4
                  Content12                    Content14
    Content21                    Content23     Content24
    Content31     Content32                    Content34
```

But currently, the table looks as follows:

```
    Header1       Header2        Header3       Header4
    Content12     Content14
    Content21     Content23      Content24
    Content31     Content32      Content34
```

Other solutions that I have looked at requires to insert the  &nbsp character when there is a null object. If I follow this approach, then for each column I have to check if the value given is null or not and insert the  &nbsp character if it is null. I think there has to be some other efficient way to do this. Can someone help me on this case?

P.S: This is a Ruby on Rails project and I am using HAML and Bootstrap for creating views. Also, my contents rows contains some extra buttons i.e. the headers row contains fewer columns than the contents row

Below is the code I have used to create the table.

```
%table.table.table-hover.table-responsive
  %thead
    %tr
      %th ID
      %th Header1
      %th Header2
      %th Header3
      %th Header4
  %tbody
    -@given_objects.each do |obj|
      %tr
        %td= obj.id
        %td= obj.content1
        %td= obj.content2
        %td= obj.content3
        %td= obj.content4
        %td= link_to 'action1', action1_path(obj), class: 'btn btn-primary'
        %td= link_to 'action2', action2_path(obj), class: 'btn btn-primary'
        %td= link_to 'action3', action3_path(obj), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Comment: Can you show the `view` code? Because HTML `<table>` should not compress like that as long as you have correct number of `<td>`s, even if these `<td>`s are empty. See this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jrpolidario/ygmnek1o/)

Comment: It's hard to offer a solution without seeing the code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I have edited the question and have provided the code structure that I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that "something" has overriden the default CSS value for the table's cell's `display` value. Probably Bootstrap? but I can just only guess...

But the following should work:

**app/assets/ANY_SCSS_FILE.scss**

```
table.show-empty-cells {
  td:empty {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

And then use the `.show-empty-cells` class for your tables:

```
%table.table.table-hover.table-responsive.show-empty-cells
```

*See [working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/jrpolidario/chsrq04a/4/)*

Comment: Tried your solution but did not help. Also, the link that you have provided does not have the working example. The table in the given example is not aligned properly.

Comment: @BijayRegmi yes, I just updated it a minute ago; can you click the `working example` link above again? As there's seem to be some bug in jsfiddle

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug or something but I the table in your working example link is still unaligned ( or at least that's what my browser is rendering)

Comment: @BijayRegmi did you try uncommenting the `/* UNCOMMENT BELOW TO FIX! */` in the HTML pane in that **working example** link, and did not fix it? You'd have to click "Run" afterwards to reprocess the page.

Comment: Actually, I did not. I tried again by uncommenting it and the working example aligns the table. However, I tried the same thing on my code, but the table in my view is still unaligned. I do not know why it is not working for my code though.

Comment: @BijayRegmi hmm... 1) did you have the `!important`?  2) probably define this CSS style at the very end of all your styles, to make sure it won't get overriden? 3) can you inspect your HTML through Chrome Inspection Tool, and check one of empty `td` inside that table, and check the "Computed" CSS value for the `display` style, and can you tell me what the value of CSS `display` is?

Comment: I did not know about the inspect tool that you can use in the browser. I am sort of newbie in RoR and web stuff. Looking at the HTML generated, I was able to find that one of the `td` tag was missing. By fixing my program logic, I was able to get the correct number of `td` in my views and it worked fine. Actually, as you have said in your first comment, I do not need any CSS to align the tables. It aligns itself. Thank you so much for your help.